# finding the right WSDL editor for API description

Tags: xml, json, web-services, api, wsdl

I am totally new to web services and XML stuff, and just learned about WSDL. I am looking for a WSDL editor that will work on a Mac and surprisingly I can't find anything online. Clearly, I am missing something...is it called something else? Is there an editor at all for WSDL?

I am trying to create a high level API behavior that this editor will then translate into XML.

Apologize in advance if what I am asking for doesn't make sense, again this is new to me, and I'd appreciate any direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you to edit WSDL on Esspreso. I don't know is shareware or freeware. I hope these helps.

Answer (score 0):

try http://apimatic.io
Import your api description and modify it according to your needs